# Cannot integrate Spring-MVC with jqGrid

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jqgrid

**Intro:** I have the files grid.jsp and invoices.jsp, among others. My Spring-MVC view resolver resolves *.htm to .jsp, so when you go to /grid.htm you get the grid.jsp view, and when you go to /invoices.htm you get the /invoices.jsp view.

---

My /invoices.htm bean is the XML file that jqGrid downloads its data from. In my invoices.jsp file, I generate an XML document based on results from the database. I output this XML document just by plainly inserting  into the file and following it by the XML structures with some  and one  tag to help me iterate through the resultset.

When I inspect the XML document (by visiting the link) it looks sound. **But for some reason my jqGrid is not recognizing any of the data.**

To make a long question short, do you think the "hoops" I have to jump through in resolving views through controllers is causing the problem? When jqGrid sends a GET request on /invoices.htm, and I resolve the view to index.jsp, is it actually downloading the XML file? In theory, everything that can be done in PHP should be capable of being ported to JSP, but is this actually the case here?

This question is hard to word, but I hope it's understandable. Thanks.

Comment: I did a test without Spring-MVC. Pure HTML, jQuery, and XML. It worked when the URL had an XML extension, but it didn't work when the URL had a .htm extension. Huh?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Spring-MVC myself, but I know about [the tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-3-dynamic-mvc-using-jqgrid-and.html) and [the previous one](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html). Probably you will find there some information which will be helpful for you.